# msbuild .net sdk version

Tags: msbuild, .net-6.0

I use msbuild to compile a project.

```
MSBuild.exe -restore /m:8 /t:Rebuild /v:Minimal /p:Configuration="Release" MyProject.sln
```

The project is based on

```xml
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

I get an error message that the package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 cannot be found. Compilation works using Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.16).

Comparing the same build process on a different machine reveals that msbuild somehow changes the .Net SDK Version to a different one.

Running above command with switch /v:diag returns

Machine 1 (Not working)

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

Machine 2 (working)

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.409\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

The project is absolutely identical on both machines. Machine 1 additionally has VS 2022 installed and I manually installed .Net SDK 6. It is not part of Visual Studio Installer.

With only the changed SDK version in mind I looked at **C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk** and found subdirectories 5.0.409, 6.0.203 and 6.0.301 among older ones.

I renamed the 6.0.203 one and msbuild works again.

The log shows that now sdk 5.0.409 is used.

I don't understand why msbuild uses 6.0.203 if present (but not the later one) or better why does msbuild think that it is a good idea to switch SDK at all?

Comment: you use "dotnet.exe" to build asp.net-core and dot.net-core apps. not "old" MsBuild.  MsBuild is for dotnet-FRAMEWORk projects.   netcoreapp3.1 means "dotnet-CORE".

Comment: @granadaCoder On Windows, msbuild can build .Net Framework and .Net (aka .Net Core). On macOS and Linux, msbuild is available and can build .Net.

Comment: The `TargetFramework` specifies the target API version and newer SDKs support older versions. The .Net 6 SDK supports net6.0, net5.0, netcoreapp3.1, and more.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification on windows machines (and msbuild still applicable). @JD